# I need to compose functions with different signatures

Tags: scala, function, composition

In scala I have two functions with different signatures. I would like to write a function that composes the two functions into a new function with a common signatures.

```
type CFunc = (Context)=>Context
type UCFunc = (Context,CFunc)=>Context
type CompF = (Context,UCFunc,CFunc)=>CFunc

val combine: CompF = (c:Context,uc:UCFunc, f:CFunc ) => ???
```

If I would execute the code, I would

```
val doIt: UCFunc = (c:Context,f:CFunc) => f(c)

def clumsy(c:Context,f:CFunc):Context = doIt(c,f)
```

It's the ??? part I'm having to figure out. I've tried a number of possibilities, none of them work. I won't enumerate what doesn't work. I know they don't work. I'm hoping that someone can help. All of the examples I've seen both functions take the same parameter list. That doesn't really help.

Lots of stuff. None of them have worked. I don't think there's a value in listing what doesn't work.

See above

A new function that evaluates to the will produce same result of the method when evaluated over the input.

Comment: How exactly do you want to compose them? Also, your types doesn't make too much sense to me, I mean, the first one is a function, and the second is a function that receives another function as argument, are you sure that is what you wanted? Try describing what you want to achieve with words.

Comment: Here are a number of possibilities: `(c1, f, g) => c2 => c1`, `(c1, f, g) => c2 => c2`, `(c1, f, g) => c2 => g(c1)`, `(c1, f, g) => c2 => g(c2)`, `(c1, f, g) => c2 => f(c1, g)`, `(c1, f, g) => c2 => f(c2, g)`, and *all of them "work"*. You don't explain what all those typedefs are, or what they are good for. Your second code snippet doesn't use `combine` anywhere. It's completely unclear what is being asked. *"None of them have worked"* is not a proper problem description, because if we don't know what those functions were supposed to do, we cannot determine whether other solutions work or not

Comment: I'm sorryI was unclear. The answer is probably in the
list you provided.

    The function f takes an Context and results in a new 
    Context. It is of type (Context=>Context).

    The function g takes a Context and a function of type 
    (Context, (Context=>Context))=>=(Context=>Context).
    a new function f' that is the result of evaluating
    the function g over the inputs of a context of
    type Context and a function of type (Context=>Context).

Comment: I want a new function f' so, when evaluated over a
    context results in a new context. A (Context=>Context).
    The same type as f.

    If I bound f' to a val of fprime I could then evaluate
    f' over any context and yeild a new Context. 

The function of doit evaluates g every time. The 
method evaluate calls doit. Generating a new function,
then evaluating the new function on ctx.

Comment: I think that's what I wrote in scala. I'm new to
the language, so might have gotten the syntax wrong. 
The combining function would normally be called by
the consumer to create a new function to pass to 
the method. I think this is called "by name" in
the scala context.

The scala solution to the problem is usually a
monad (I think). Monads are a pain in the but for
this kind of problem. It requires the consumer to 
know the implementation of evaluate then override
it to do the identical function, but with extra bits.

Comment: I've come across it using Option and Try. I want
to add those features to my functions without having
to know the implementation of evaluated and overriding
it every time I consume the trait again.

I might be wrong in my style. I am placing all behavior
in traits. Each trait is a collection of functions. I'm
also trying to provide traits that allow the consumers
to rewrite functions to meet their needs. Traits are
types, a collection of functions that operate together.
The function part of a group. The Type statements provide
the input types (or set) of the functions.

Comment: All of my classes so far have been restricted to data. All
are final classes. Sometimes case classes to reduce the
number and complexity of compainion objects. Perhaps I'm
being too lispy. Lisp has no methods. Classes and functions.
Functions are specialized on the classes. The equivalent
to overriding methods. 

Sorry about not listing what I've tried. They were all wrong
and would mislead the reader in what I was trying to do.

Unfortunately, it also made my intensions unclear.

Comment: @DavidHoyt Sorry, I still do not understand what do you want... It may be my poor English, sorry. I think you may get more luck asking in the [**Scala** _gitter_ channel](https://gitter.im/scala/scala). And, when asking there, Try to provide example input and expected output, also, you may use [**Scatie**](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/) to provide your code - Also, as an advice for future questions, when answering comments tag the person you are answering _(with @name)_, otherwise we do not get a notification, you were lucky that I sometimes check all questions I have commented recently.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think to λ for scala to be transparent for me.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: "None of them have worked" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it. I hope I transcribed the solution correctly.
An example with Try

```
> Context holds the context of the functions. 
> > I - input to function  (read by f)
> > R - result of function (updated by f)
> > E - exception causing an error (updated by TryF)
> > > Update - copies the old context, notes the exception 
> 
> > val tryF = (f:Context=>Context) => 
> > > Try(f(c)) match {
> > > > case Success(ok) => ok
> > > > case Failure(e)  => c.update(Option(e))
> > > > case _           => c.update(Option(new MatchError(f))
> > > }
```

Comment: Oops "c" is established by

   val tryF = (f:Context=>Context) => (c:Context)=> ...